# Page not fully loaded (html source cut off) in IE8

Tags: php, apache, internet-explorer

I have a strange problem: I have a PHP application that's working in all common browsers. But some pages are not fully loaded in IE8. If I look at the source code, it has been more ore less randomly cut off and half of the html source is missing, sometimes in the middle of a tag.

The strange thing is, it appears only on some IE-installations (in a big company), on others (I'd say the majority) it's working.

If I look up the apache error logs it says:

```
[notice] child pid 9393 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I don't know if it's related somehow, but how can the same page (called with the same parameters) work on one machine and not on another one (reproducable)?

I have not a single clue if it's some rendering problems in IE, if the browser is crashing internally or if the server really crashes and serving only half of the html source.

(Unfortunately I can't provide an example as it occurs on a web project yet to be released)

---

Update: I did some testing:

1. Upgraded Apache2, PHP5, libPHP5 on the Debian machine. Updated, activated, deactivated xdebug, mimicked the request header (user-agent) with apaches mod_header - still the same problem. Honestly I'm not sure, if the seg fault has something to do with the problem that IE only delivers half of the content.

Can this also be due to a virus scanner? Does anyone know of circumstances that IE only gets half the source code when there is no server error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of debugging (updated server software, moved to another machine and so on) we finally got the problem. It was a very old installation of the Novell Border Manager, some sort of proxy. The segmentation fault seems to be unrelated to this.

If anyone has similar problems, here are two related posts:

http://www.novell.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=7007318&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_TID_1_1

http://forums.novell.com/novell-product-support-forums/access-manager-3/428004-access-manager-showing-partial-content-page-post2058485.html

Answer (score 3):

If your Apache logs say one of the worker processes segfaulted, it's not a client-side issue.  No matter what the client does, it should not cause the server to crash.

The issue *might* be related to IE8, but only indirectly - IE8 could issue a different pattern of requests when visiting the page, or at the very least sends a different User-Agent string which the server might use to follow a different codepath.

Try upgrading your version of Apache.  If that doesn't work, check for configuration errors in Apache, such as a bad extension module.  If that doesn't do it, inspect your server hardware for flaws.

Comment: +1 and if that doesn't help, you may need to start looking at the PHP code. Is there any browser detection going on, and the application behaving differently depending on the results?

Comment: I find it rather strange that it works with the same browser on a different machine (running the same browser version and the same OS).

Comment: I updated the OP. I mimicked the user-agent, upgraded the server software, still the same problem. I'm not sure if this is really a server problem as it works on every other combination of browser/OS I tried. Maybe the segfault is another error that's not relating to this one?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no answer, bt if it were me I'd....

1) configure the php to do an auto-prepend (unless there's already one in place
2) write an include file to trap incomplete page loads (have a llok at ignore_user_abort, connection_status and register_shutdown_function)

If your code can detect occurrences of the problem, then its not related to the segfault.

You might also try installing mod_security which can log post vars and record a log entry at the start of a request - so you have some scope for investigating the segfaults.